# certmgr.exe doesn't have an import function on Windows 7

Tags: ssl, windows-7, ssl-certificate

I'm using windows 7 & want to import a certificate.  [This link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/import-or-export-certificates-and-private-keys) says to use the Action => All Tasks => Import menu on certmgr.exe, but my instance of certmgr.exe is missing that menu item.  I tried running as an administrator but it still doesn't show.  What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

OK, The problem was that I hadn't selected a certificate store. Once I did that then the Import menu item showed up.